# Adding integer and double in java

Tags: java

I am working on a JavaFX project at school, and at the moment I am stuck with a problem.
I want to add the sum of some numbers defined in a class (see the class Add) which have both double and integer. At the moment the code I have is not compiling.

```
public class Add {
    
    private double numdob;
    private int numint;
    
    
    public void setNumdob(double numdob) {
        this.numdob = numdob;
    }
    
    public void setNumint(int numint) {
        this.numint = numint;
    }
    
    public double getNumdob() {
        return numdob;
    }
    
    public double getNumint() {
        return numint;
    }

    
    public double calculateSum() {
        double numdob = 10.0*getNumdob();
        int numint = (int) (3.31*getNumint());
        
        double total = numdob + numint;
        return total;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to use the method in a in a controller(javaFX), where I am have implemented the method like this: (I have initialized and defined the class above )

```
    private Add add;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        add = new Add();

    @FXML
    public void calculate() {
        try {
            double numdob = Double.parseDouble(double.getText());
            int numint = Integer.parseInt(integer.getText());
            
            
            add.setNumdob(numdob);
            add.setNumint(numint);

            
            double totalSum = add.calculateSum();
            
            output.setText("The sum is " + totalSum);
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            outputCustoms.setText( e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: At the moment it does not return any "total"

Comment: Do you use `setNumdob(...)` and `setNumint(...)` before you use `calculateSum()`? If not, then you have not initalised `numdob` and `numint` so it will not run.

Comment: @Jon: it totally does return the total (pun intended). Did you expect `return total` to actually **print** the total to the screen? Because for this you'll need to explicitly do something like `System.out.println(calculateSum())`. Returning a value is not the same as printing it.

Comment: I have tried to update my question for the better...

Comment: @Jon:  the second sample that you show does not compile. For *multiple* reasons. Are you looking for help in making it compile?

Comment: Of course it doesn't return a "total", because the code doesn't compile, and hence can't run.

Comment: Yes, need help to make it compile

Comment: The issue seems to be just a couple of typos.  You forgot the closing brace on the `initialize()` method, and you seem to have tried to name a variable `double`, but `double` is reserved keyword.  There might also be more I'm not seeing right away.

Comment: Specifically this does not work `Double.parseDouble(double.getText());` you cannot name a component `double`, first fix the name, then you need to replace `double.getText()` with your actual text component name like this `Double.parseDouble(yourComponent.getText());`

Answer (score 0):

You do not declare (or show us?) vars such as `integer` or `output`.

Another small problem is this:

```java
    public double getNumint() {
        return numint;
    }
```

… should return `int` rather than double.

## Revamped code

I revised your code. My changes include:

- Renaming the class as `Add` is not clear. I expect you could devise an even better name than my `CalcPair` given your knowledge of your problem domain.
- Making the class immutable. Generally best to go immutable until you determine mutability is required. In this case here, instantiating a new `CalcPair` is just as simple and easy as calling setters and recalculating — so no point in being mutable.
- Cache the result of the calculation. Perform the calculation in the constructor, and save to a member field.
- Added a call to [`Math.toIntExact​( long value )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact(long)) to detect if your result does not fit a 32-bit `int` value. Your initial result is cast to a `long` before converting to an `int`.
- Appended `d` to the literals to make clear they are intended to be of type `double`.

```java
package work.basil.demo.math;

import java.util.Objects;

public final class CalcPair
{
    // Member fields.
    private final double numdob;
    private final int numint;
    private final double result;

    // Constructors.
    public CalcPair ( final double numdob , final int numint )
    {
        this.numdob = numdob;
        this.numint = numint;
        // Calculate result
        double x = ( 10.0d * this.numdob );
        int y = Math.toIntExact( ( long ) ( 3.31d * this.numint ) );  // Truncate `double` fractional to a `long` integer, then fit to an `int`. The `Math.toIntExact` call throws exception if beyond the bounds of `int` type.
        this.result = ( x + y );
    }

    // Getters.

    public double numdob ( ) { return numdob; }

    public int numint ( ) { return numint; }

    public double result ( ) { return this.result; }

    // `Object` overrides.

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( final Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        CalcPair calcPair = ( CalcPair ) o;
        return Double.compare( calcPair.numdob , numdob ) == 0 && numint == calcPair.numint;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( numdob , numint );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "CalcPair{ " +
                "numdob=" + numdob +
                " | numint=" + numint +
                " | result=" + result +
                " }";
    }
}
```

Usage.

```java
double numdob = Double.parseDouble( "7" );
int numint = Integer.parseInt( "42" );
CalcPair calcPair = new CalcPair( numdob , numint );
double result = calcPair.result();

System.out.println( "result = " + result );
```

> result = 209.0

By the way, understand that floating-point technology [trades away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed-of-execution. If you care about accuracy, use `BigDecimal` rather than float/Float/double/Double types.